# Convert SQL statement to SQLAlchemy

Tags: sql, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I need to convert this SQL statement to an SQLAlchemy ORM query:

```sql
SELECT zone, count(fall_status)
FROM events
WHERE events.timestamp BETWEEN 1663460366 AND 1663546766
AND events.fall_status = 1 
GROUP by zone
```

Comment: Please provide what you have tried and where you ran into a problem.

Comment: I'm using this code in python fast API    SELECT zone, count(fall_status)
FROM events
WHERE events.timestamp BETWEEN 1663460366 AND 1663546766
AND events.fall_status = 1 
GROUP by zone   <==== this is code snippet but i want events = db.query(Events).filter(Events.timestamp.between(to_date,from_date)).all() this formate of python

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create an engine:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = engine = create_engine('sqlite:///...')
```

Then you can use

```
from sqlalchemy.sql import text
with engine.connect() as conn:
    statement = text("SELECT zone, count(fall_status) from events WHERE events.timestamp BETWEEN 1663460366 AND 1663546766 AND events.fall_status = 1 GROUP by zone")
conn.execute(statement)
```

Comment: events = db.query(Events).filter(Events.timestamp.between(to_date,from_date)).all()
 i need like this

Answer (score 0):

```py
q = (
    db.query(
        Events.zone, 
        func.count(Events.fall_status),
    )
    .filter(Events.fall_status == 1)
    .filter(Events.timestamp.between(to_date,from_date))
    .group_by(Events.zone)
).all()
```

see [func.count](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/functions.html#sqlalchemy.sql.functions.count)